# OpenCV take pixel color values

Tags: c++, opencv

I know there are a lot of similar questions like this, though for some reason I can't seem to find what I am looking for.

I need to take the RGB(BGR in Open_cv) values. What i have tried and I believe is wrong (cause taking one random pixel value of a JPEG image with eye dropper tool found values that never appeared on my program).

Code:

```
cv::Vec3b intensity;
intensity = img1.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j);
blue1 = intensity.val[0];
green1 = intensity.val[1];
red1 = intensity.val[2];
```

Comment: "taking one random pixel value of a jpeg" - jpg is lossy, prefer bmp or ppm images for experiments like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is correct. Just check you are not getting, for example, `i,j` swapped around. The first index is the *row*. See the example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at).

Another thing to check: which is the type of blue1, green1, red1? Should be `unsigned char`, a.k.a. `uint8_t`, or equivalent. And you should be careful, if you do, on how you print the values on the `std::cout` (need a cast to `int`).

Comment: @S11 Glad this helped, what was the problem exactly?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you

```
  cv::Mat image; //Some image
 uint8_t r,g,b;
 if (image.channels() == 1) { // gray-level image
 g=image.at<uchar>(j,i);
 } else if (image.channels() == 3) { // RGB color image
 r=image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0];//R
 b=image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1];//B
 g=image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2];//G
 }
```

all the best

Comment: This is *setting* pixel values!! And, at least in the comments, you swapped R and B (according to OpenCV use)

Comment: well then just swap left and right hand side and replace the number by variables.... as done in the corrected version....